# SQL for UTC Conversion

Tags: sql, timezone, utc, delta-lake

I have 2 columns in a table as follows,

```
TIMESTAMP                          TIMEZONE
2020-08-20T02:36:52.000+0000       PST
2020-08-20T02:36:52.000+0000       GMT
2020-08-20T02:36:52.000+0000       CST
```

Now I want to convert those timestamp column data to UTC column.. But the conversion should be based on the timestamp and the timezone column. I can do it on a dataframe. But I have to do it on SQL.

Please help on how to use both the columns to derive respective UTC Timestamp data for each record.

Comment: Please tag the database engine you’re using

Comment: ... because many dbms products have their own date/time functions, non-ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: You should avoid time zone abbreviations, as they can be ambiguous.  For example, "CST" can mean "Central Standard Time", "Cuba Standard Time", or "China Standard Time".

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer for this,

SELECT to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, timezone) from tablename;

This will sort the issue..